# How to import KIE-Workbench project from git repository

Tags: git, tomcat7, kie

I'm using KIE workbench 6.5.0 & KIE Server 6.5.0. i created the repository and project in my local system. I download the project and push it to git repo. But i unable to pull that project from repo to my server.
Pls help me to solve this fix.

Thanks in advance,
Vishnu K.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat documentation shows how to clone a remote repository and configure a git hook to automatically push to the remote repository using a `post-commit` file in the git clone.

1. Go to Authoring -> Administration
2. Repositories -> Clone repository
3. Fill your distant git repository address and credentials.
4. After clone, go to your server disk and create a `post-commit` file under `JBOSS_HOME/bin/.niogit/REPOSITORY_NAME.git/hooks` with content :

`#!/bin/sh`

`git push origin master`

For more details, have a look at [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap_repository_hooks#configuring_git_hooks)

Just a hint : you should let workbench create the projects structure and clone a repository which has no content yet. However, your repository should not be completely empty before cloning it. If workbench has the same bug than business central, cloning a bare repo may fail with a `NoSuchElementException`. Be sure to push a single file, for instance a README file, at the root of your repository.